# Sorting XML data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, sorting

I wanted to ask how i can sort my XML file by "glossary_term_heading"? I have looked at other examples but cannot seem to get it to work. Thanks in advance.

XML:

```
<glossary>

<glossary_term>
<glossary_term_heading><![CDATA[Title 1]]></glossary_term_heading>
<glossary_term_content><![CDATA[<P>content 1</P>]]>
</glossary_term_content>
</glossary_term>

<glossary_term>
<glossary_term_heading><![CDATA[Title 2]]></glossary_term_heading>
<glossary_term_content><![CDATA[<P>content 2</P>]]>
</glossary_term_content>
</glossary_term>

</glossary>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        // Connect to the XML file
        type: "GET",
        url: "glossary.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find('glossary_term').each(function(){ // find each glossary term
                var glossary_term_heading = $(this).find("glossary_term_heading").text(); // find the glossary term heading
                var glossary_term_content = $(this).find("glossary_term_content").text(); // find the glossary term content

                $('<h1 class="glossary_term_heading"></h1>').html(''+glossary_term_heading+'').appendTo('#page-wrap'); // add the glossary term heading into H1 tags
                $('<div class="glossary_term_content"></div>').html(''+glossary_term_content+'').appendTo('#page-wrap'); // add the glossary term content into div

                }); // xml.find end

            }

    }); // Ajax end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of terms, and sort it and then iterate over the sorted array like

```
 $.ajax({
     // Connect to the XML file
     type: "GET",
     url: "glossary.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function (xml) {

         //find the terms array
         var terms = $(xml).find('glossary_term').get();
         //sort the terms
         terms.sort(function (t1, t2) {
             var h1 = $.trim($(t1).find('glossary_term_heading').text()),
                 h2 = $.trim($(t2).find('glossary_term_heading').text());
             return h1.localeCompare(h2)
         })

         //iterate over the sorted array
         $.each(terms, function () {
             var glossary_term_heading = $(this).find("glossary_term_heading").text(); // find the glossary term heading
             var glossary_term_content = $(this).find("glossary_term_content").text(); // find the glossary term content

             $('<h1 class="glossary_term_heading"></h1>').html('' + glossary_term_heading + '').appendTo('#page-wrap'); // add the glossary term heading into H1 tags
             $('<div class="glossary_term_content"></div>').html('' + glossary_term_content + '').appendTo('#page-wrap'); // add the glossary term content into div

         }); // xml.find end

     }

 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2zgef/)